# I can't read shared memory in C

Tags: c, shared-memory

I have a program with two processes and two files and I want to read a var with the code of the second file by shared memory but I only get the "testing" word, not the text. the code of first file of the program:

```
a=shmget(key, 200, 0666|IPC_CREAT);
text=(char *)shmat(a,0,0);
text=&words[0];
     if ((P2=fork())==1)
     {
     perror("fork");
     exit(-1);
     }
          if (P2==0)
          {
          execl("prog2","prog2",NULL);
          }
```

And the code of the second file:

```
a=shmget(key, 200, 0666);
text=shmat(a,0,SHM_RDONLY);
printf("testing, %s", text);
```

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: also `fork() == -1` not 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never put anything in the shared memory; you just changed the value of `text` to point to something other than the shared memory.

Instead of:

```
text=&words[0];
```

You probably wanted something like:

```
memcpy(text, &words[0], strlen(words[0]) + 1);
```